# How to deploy create-react-app in subdirectory to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, create-react-app

I have the following setup in my github repo (NOTE: my `package.json` is in `/dashboard` subfolder. Problem?). My problem is that i cannot deploy a create-react-app thats in a subdirectory with Heroku (This error happens upon deployment -> "`App not compatible with buildpack: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git`"). Is there a way to move `/dashboard` to the root of the repo? Or can i use another hosting service (Netlify)? I have tried other solutions such as using config vars in Heroku settings, but still doesnt work. Step by step process would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**: for anyone who comes across in future, the simplest way by far is to instead use Netlify -- Log in, then drag your root folder into drag and drop area under "Sites", then under Settings -> Build & Deploy -> Continuous Deployment -> Build settings (connect Netlify to Github repo first) youll enter the subdirectory name into Base Directory field (no slashes), then `CI= npm run build` for Build Command, and finally `yourSubdirectoryName/build` for Publish Directory field. Save and then trigger another deployment.